# automatically changing model field in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

Consider a Blog model as below:

```
class Blog(models.Model):
    text = ...
    stage = ... # ChoiceField
```

`Blog.stage` describes the current stage the blog is in which can take many values like `edit`, `content verification`, `tag` etc. Transition from one stage to another is based on a condition.

In content verification stage, a user verifies the content of the model and corresponding entries are recorded in the following model.

```
class ContentVerificationModel(models.Model):
    user = ... #verifier 
    blog = ... # blog being verified
    do_you_verify_blog_content = ... # BooleanField
```

To move from content_verification_stage to next stage, say, edit stage, following conditions must be satisfied:

1. Blog must be verified by some minimum number of people (Say, 10)
2. Percentage of people who voted for the blog must be greater than some minimum value (say, 60 i.e. 6 out 10 entries for a blog must have `do_you_verify_blog_content` value as `True`)

How do I manipulate my code so that a model field can be changed **automatically** when some conditions are met?

Comment: See [Model signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/signals/#module-django.db.models.signals)

Comment: Yes, as per @AshishNitinPatil's Suggestion, you need to call a signal. You should write a post_save signal for ContentVerificationModel model. Whenever a user verified a blog, signal will get called. You can write your logic for verification of blog over there.